# Negative Supply

Tags: integrated-circuit, negative-voltage

I am thinking to test an IC which have +9V and -9V supplies. To obtain a -9V, i intend to reverse connect a +9V battery. What can be negative effects, if there is? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you show a schematic of what you have intended to do?  There's a built in schematic editor, it's pretty easy to learn.  And there's always the good old paper and pen method iff nothing else works.

Answer (score 1):

> What can be negative effects,

Was this a pun? You are looking for negative effects!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqV4DO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A +/- 9 V supply using two 9 V batteries.*

> I intend to reverse connect a +9V battery.

We would probably say that we will *series connect* the batteries connecting one positive to the next negative and not "reversing" them. The idea is to keep all the voltages pointing the same direction.

Otherwise your understanding is correct.

Comment: I have seen on some applications using a full wave rectifier and a transformer instead of this. Thats why i was asking whether there is a problem if i configure like this.

Comment: Yes, you can get the same thing with a centre-tapped transformer and rectifier (and smoothing capacitors, and maybe some voltage regulators ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to go for a package solution existing, I would recommend using a DC/DC converter such as: [TracoPower-TMR Series Datasheet](http://assets.tracopower.com/20161003112443/TMR2/documents/tmr-datasheet.pdf). I have used this one for OP-Amp dual supplies and it works fine.

It allows the dual output setting, where you can convert your input voltage (9V) to a dual +- voltage. Of course the corresponding part shall be selected accordingly.